# Is there a subset of irrationals of size $\mathfrak{d}$ whose image, under any bijection to the Baire space, remains dominating?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Given any bijection $\varphi$ between the irrationals and $\omega^\omega$, and a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \mathbb{Q}$ of size $\mathfrak{d}$ ,  under which properties $\varphi(A)$ is dominating?
What about the question in the title?
I guess we should assume $\mathfrak{d} < \mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the title question, the answer is no, when d is less than c, because you could map your set into the 2-valued functions and map the complement to the rest. So the image would not be dominating.

Comment: Of course. Thank you. I didn't think about that :-)

Comment: +1. And in fact we only really need the property that the complement of $A$ is large - that $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ has size continuum.